# How to create facebook open graph objects and actions?

Tags: api, facebook-opengraph

I have created a few apps in facebook and also tried out open graph on them. I have created the open graph objects and actions by going to the app's settings page. I would like to know if I can create these objects and actions programmatically using facebook api or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this programmatically. Creating objects and actions are very hands-on and require that the developer takes interest in how those objects and actions are designed in display to provide a deep-social experience with your users. Keeping it to UI activity forces the developer to be mindful of the verbs, types and items he/she uses.